# @Component Springs annotation not working

Tags: spring, annotations

I am using Springs framework 3.2.0. and i am not able to use @component annotation. Below is the error which i received when Test.java was executed.
I tried changing the java version, and springs framework version but nothing worked.

**Beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="util-namespace"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ds.cab.car" />


    <bean id="e" class="com.ds.cab.engine.Engine">
        <property name="modelyear" value="2015 AUDI"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Car.java**

```
package com.ds.cab.car;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ds.cab.engine.Engine;

@Component
public class Car {
    @Autowired
    private Engine engine;

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public void printData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Engine model year: "+engine.getModelyear());
    }
}
```

**Engine.java**

```
package com.ds.cab.engine;

public class Engine {
    private String modelyear;

    public void setModelyear(String modelyear) {
        this.modelyear = modelyear;
    }
    public String getModelyear() {
        return modelyear;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
package ioc;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.ds.cab.car.Car;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        Car c = (Car)ctx.getBean(Car.class);
        c.printData();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [E:\Prakhar\STS Workspace\StereoTyping01\bin\com\ds\cab\car\Car.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at ioc.Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Downgrade java or upgrade to spring 4.0. Spring 3.2 doesn't work with JDK8 compiled classes.

Comment: i am using springs 4.3.5 and JDK 8...

Comment: Not according to your question, you explicitly state `3.2.0` and not `4.3.5`. So which is it? If you are really using 4.3 remove the `spring-asm` dependency.

Comment: after your comment i upgraded spring to 4.3.5. Still no luck

Comment: it worked for me
with Springs framework 3.2.0 and jre 7

thanks M.Deinum

Comment: If you are on `4.3` you probably stil have the old `spring-asm` around remove that dependency.

Comment: i was only working with 5 dependencies which are 

beans , expression , context , core , commons-logging

Comment: You must be pulling it in from somewhere this exception only occurs if th old `spring-asm` is on the class path. It should work with Spring 4.x and up with JDK8. You might want to do a `mvn dependency:tree` to check what you are pulling in .

Answer (score 0):

Create a Car bean and inject your engine bean into it (e represents your engine bean name):

```
<bean id="Car" class = "com.ds.cab.car.Car">
    <constructor-arg ref="e"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Good point Autowired annotations allow for easy declarations of beans however by just adding "component-scan:" it enables everything that <context:annotation-config /> can do, with addition of using stereotypes eg.. Component, Service , Repository. So you can wire entire beans and not just restricted to constructors or properties!.

Answer (score 0):

In your beans.xml,

1. Change component-scan into

   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.ds.cab.car" />`
2. Remove engine bean declarion.
3. Add `@Component` annotation to Car Class.

Comment: then how will i set the "modelyear" property inside Engine class.??

and the component-scan tag is already there in the file..

Comment: it worked for me with Springs framework 3.2.0 and jre 7